# Deleted miniconda folder, python won't run

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, miniconda

I installed/ miniconda in the following directory:

```
/home/arturo/Documents/project1/pwd
```

but then I deleted it by typing:

```
rm -r pwd/
```

Now I can't run python anymore (from any directory). Not really sure what happened. I get this error:

```
bash: /home/arturo/Documents/project1/pwd/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think a `hash -r` would suffice to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least two choices:

1. Reinstall miniconda, into the same location as before.
2. Clear the executable cache with `hash -r` to eliminate the stale entry, which ties the python command to non-existent `/home/arturo/Documents/project1/pwd/bin/python` cf. [What is the purpose of the hash command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command)

Comment: I don't want to install miniconda on root (I'll reinstall on virtual env probably), so I guess option 2 would be the best fit? (Option 2 worked btw!)